# When cluster end, “State changed from up to crashed”. It should fork()

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a master and slave app.
Locally on my computer, everything works : when a slave dies because of a 
`process.exit(0)` , I fork and it goes on.

I catch it with,

```
cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    if(code == 0){
        cluster.fork();
    }
});
```

Sadly on Heroku, as soon as the slave execute process.exit(0) the `"State changed from up to crashed"`

Any idea to bypass Heroku safeguards ?

Comment: You need to post your app code, Procfile, and any log messages when the dyno crashed.  This snippet looks correct, so something else must be going on.

Comment: Please post logs and procfile. Instead of bypassing safeguards, you must try to find the root cause.

Answer (score 5):

Heroku dynos are a virtual application container built with required binaries from buildpacks and combined with a release of your application code.  The only job of this app container is to run a process described by your `Procfile`.

If that process terminates unexpectedly, Heroku considers the dyno crashed and will attempt to restart the process.  Also, if the app doesn't bind to the designated `PORT` within 60 seconds, the dyno will be crashed.

If your backend worker processes are not binding to the port when they come up, before issuing `process.exit(0)`, they will never listen on the port.  If the dyno doesn't bind to the port within the timeout, Heroku will consider it crashed.

My guess is that you are immediately exiting each child worker process, causing the master to fork `N` children, then re-fork each one, until the boot timeout is hit.